# Jquery Get call failing in cloud environment

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

i pulling the some values from databases by J-query Ajax get Request by.

```
/Helper/ActionName?imageids=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5
```

`Jquery` code Snippet.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: AcredationUri,
            data: { imageids: accredationlist }, //accredationlist
            type: 'GET',
            traditional: true,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                    acccontent = '';
                    $(data).each(function () {
                        acccontent += buildAccedationAccord(this);
                    });
                }
                $('#' + hid).find('.acimg').append(acccontent);
                $('#' + hid).find('.acimg').unblock();
            }
        });
```

but this works  in emulator environment and results the data. but same code is not working on cloud environment.

the Response which captured in firebug is `XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{388b700f-8bb6-4ae5-a926-8d8fb6ec8c4c} Line Number 1, Column 1:`

**Note**: *I am not making any cross domains calls. but the error is prompted is about cross domain*.

fiddler is not reporting anything unusual.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 05:04:04 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I am expecting a `JSON` response from this method. but not able to find out what is wrong here.